# Angular $htttp : to which asynch call did I get the reply?

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous

I go to a server and get a JSON array contaminating an array of a lat/long pair & some other info (e.g vehicle description, time stamp). For each of those, I want to use Google maps to reverse geocode & get the street address then put it the data into an ng-grid.

My ng-Grid is bound to `$scope.myGrid` and, until now, without reverse geocoding, I was just looping though the JSON data and `$scope.myGrid.push('{When: data[i].time_stamp, Vehicle: data[i].description'}`.

That was working fine, now I want to add reverse geocoding which, AFAIK, means using `$http.get`.

Since this is asynchronous, I initially populate the grid's "address" column with "[address not available]".

When I get the response, I want to set `$scope.myGrid[???].address` from the result.

**BUT**, how do I know what the index `???` is? If I have 3 outstanding asynch requests and get a response, how do I know which grid row it corresponds to?

My `$http.get` is in the middle of a `for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)` loop. Can I somehow pass `i` to the `$http.get` fucntion? Or how else do I do it?

Sorry, I'm just learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use 'for', you need use a Anonymous function to do this. pass i to Anonymous function.

```
for(var i = 0; i < $scope.myGrid.length; i++){
  (function(i){
    $http.get(...).success(function(data){
      $scope.myGrid[i].address = data
    });
  })(i);
}
```

IMHO, "forEach" maybe better in your case

```
$scope.myGrid.forEach(function(item, i){
  //item equels $scope.myGrid[i]
  $http.get(...).success(function(data){
    item.address = data
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I used `forEach` as you advised.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `$http` needs to be aware of `i`, but its `then` success callback does. Something like the following should be helpful.

```
angular.forEach(data, function(datum, i) {
  $http.get(...).then(function(response) {
    // Here you have the response and i available
  });
});
```

Note: I have deliberately used `angular.forEach` rather than the `for` loop. Because of the nature of the `i` variable in `for`, if you have asynchronous callbacks defined within the `for` loop, `i` will actually always be equal to its final value, `data.length - 1` for every callback. Using `angular.forEach` avoids this issue.